# How do I concatenate three columns in a pandas dataframe, joined by an underscore `_`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concatenate the values of each row in columns 1-3 and save it as a pandas series. The concatenated values will be joined by underscore `_`.

```
import pandas as pd
# Create the ID series by concatenating columns 1-3
self.df["ID"] = df[["cell_id:cell_id", "region:region", "tile_num:tile_num"]].apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Traceback:

```
>   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/CODEX/main.py", line 24, in
> raw_file_processing
>     self.df["ID"] = df[["cell_id:cell_id", "region:region", "tile_num:tile_num"]].apply(lambda row:
> '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1) TypeError: 'NoneType' object
> does not support item assignment
```

**Original dataframe `df`**

| cell_id:cell_id | region:region | tile_num:tile_num | ABC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

**Desired output**

| ID | ABC |
| --- | --- |
| 1_2_3 | 4 |
| 5_6_7 | 8 |

Comment: Your code works for me. You may have a dataframe attribute `ID` set somewhere that is equal `None`. But the problem is not in the code or data you're showing.

Comment: `self.df` is `None`. `None['ID'] = 1` Reproduces the error message shown.

Answer (score 0):

The code for your **specific example:**

```
df=df.assign(
    ID=df[['cell_id:cell_id','region:region','tile_num:tile_num']].apply(
        lambda row: '_'.join([str(each) for each in row]),axis=1))

df = df.drop(columns=['cell_id:cell_id','region:region','tile_num:tile_num'])
```

**More generally:**

If you have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2],'col2':[3,4],'col3':[5,6]})
```

ie:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

Then you can do:

```
df=df.assign(
    ID=df[['col1','col2']].apply(
        lambda row: '_'.join([str(each) for each in row]),axis=1))
```

which will give you:

```
   col1  col2  col3   ID
0     1     3     5  1_3
1     2     4     6  2_4
```

If you don't want to keep the columns used to creade the new column:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['col1','col2'])
```

`df` becomes:

```
   col3   ID
0     5  1_3
1     6  2_4
```